# How can I Fill a Dataset with data from an IQueryable?

Tags: linq, ado.net

Is there any quick way to create a table in a dataset and fill it with the schema from an IQueryable (Data is not coming from EF or Linq2Sql)?  I need this for binding a grid to my data.

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: how are you getting the IQuerable?

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing "fill it with the schema". Do you mean that the schema of the objects in your IQueryable is unknown at design-time? i.e. you have to create a DataTable with columns that are figured out at run-time from the type of objects in the IQueryable and then load the data from the IQueryable into the DataTable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Translate function of the System.Data.Linq.DataContext class to "automatically" map a Table into a Class.

There is an example:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



    string cnnStr = "YourConnectionString";
    DataContext dc = new DataContext(cnnStr);
    SqlConnection sqlCnn = (SqlConnection) dc.Connection;
    sqlCnn.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select ID, Name, [Date] From test", sqlCnn);
    SqlDataReader sqlDr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    var result = dc.Translate<clsRow>(sqlDr);
    foreach(clsRow row in result)
    {
       Console.Write(row.ID);
       Console.Write(row.Name);
       Console.Write(row.Date);
    }
```

In this case, you need a table called Test with 3 columns: ID, Name and Test 
and also a class called clsRow in .Net with the same properties name of the table columns.

```
public class clsRow
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```